# Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) but 'gem list' has 'bundler' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

For a `bundle install` command, I get the error:

```
Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0)
```

But `gem list` says bundler gem is already installed.

Full output here - https://gist.github.com/emaillenin/2ad3569bf537e2bb58a0

How to use the bundle install command?

Comment: Looks like your command is trying to use a specific gemset, and you probably don't have bundler installed in that gemset.

Comment: are you in the project directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

`/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm 2.2.3@duggout-app do bundle install`

means `bundle install` is executed under Ruby 2.2.3 and gemset `duggout-app`. It switches the environment from the default one, where you ran `gem list`.

If you would instead run

`/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm 2.2.3@duggout-app do gem list`

you would see the gems installed in that gemset, and

`/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm 2.2.3@duggout-app do gem install bundler`

will fix your issue.

If you want, you can change the default version & gemset using an `.rvmrc` file, but I think that in this deploy scenario it isn't necessary.